# pycharm, edit configuration parameters for pytest are not working

Tags: command-line, pycharm, pytest

I have a simple test that takes the parameter --test from command line and compares it.  It works just fine in command line, but when I use pycharm it is no longer working (will not take the parameter from command line in my configuration set up in pycharm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9GRh.png)

I guess, there is something wrong with my pycharm set up, but I can't figure out what it is...
I have found where and how to set up the configuration, but it's just not working...are the command line parser.addoption parameters added in the parameters window of the configuration?
is the syntax --test test_type_name or --test="test_type_name" I have tried them all...
Using a community version of pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I had to put them in additional arguments window instead of Parameters, I thought I had tried it and it didn't work before.  I also had an old version of pycharm, from last year - could have had a bug in it, I have since updated to something newer and it works.